# multiple clients querying data with no server

Tags: java, database, serialization, embedded, client

I'm working on a school project where the client needs to have multiple users querying and writing to a single data source. The users have access to shared network drives and all functionality has to be in the client application, the IT department won't allow a service to run from one of their servers and external server hosting isn't an option.

The amount of data that actually needs to be stored is actually very little, about 144 rows maximum.

I've looked into using embedded databases, sqllite , hsql , objectdb ... etc but they seem over kill for how little data needs to be saved. It also seemed like with hsql if anyone accessed the database it would be completely locked to any other user. Concurrency wouldn't be much of an issue there will be 5-7 people using the system albeit scarcely only a few times a year.

Would using something like XQuery and serializing everything in xml be a viable option or just simply using the java serializable api?

Comment: If you school's IT department doesn't allow you to run your project, you should really talk to your professor rather than us.

Comment: That's more of a constrain on how it can be implemented, the users will have an application running from their desktops. It's just that they can't communicate with a server application. They would all be accessing the same data on a network drive.

Answer (score 1):

A distributed, client side database writing files to the shared network drive could be a good solution for this use case. Take a look at [Cloud DB](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html), it might be what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks i'm looking into it now.